# Cannot read local files to docker compose

Tags: python, docker, ssl, gunicorn

I am trying to add SSL to my Django app in the backend.

On my VPS, I created the certificate files, that are in the path:

```
'/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.it/fullchain.pem'
'/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.it/privkey.pem'
```

And to let them be read I wrote that in the docker compose file of the django service:

````
volumes:
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.it/fullchain.pem:/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.it/fullchain.pem
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.it/privkey.pem:/etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.it/privkey.pem```
````

So, to use the files for HTTPS, I am setting up gunicorn file in this way, so that it is able to use the key to let the traffic arrive and be decripted. Here is what I wrote in `gunicorn.conf.py`:

```
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from os import environ

# Server Socket
bind = '0.0.0.0:' + environ.get('PORT', '443')
max_requests = 1000
workers = cpu_count()
timeout = 30

# Logging
loglevel ='info'
accessformat = '%(t)s %(h)s %(l)s %(r)s %(s)s %(b)s %(f)s %(a)s'
accesslog = '-'
errorlog = '-'

# SSL
certfile = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.my-table.it/fullchain.pem'
keyfile = '/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.my-table.it/privkey.pem'
ssl_version = 2
```

But an error occurs when I run it on the server with docker-compose, and says that:

```
    self.LISTENERS = sock.create_sockets(self.cfg, self.log, fds)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   File "/home/devuser/.local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 162, in create_sockets
    raise ValueError('certfile "%s" does not exist' % conf.certfile)
 ValueError: certfile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/api.my-table.it/fullchain.pem" does not exist
```

I was wondering if I was missing something, or how I could import the file successfully, so that I can import the keys and use HTTPS via gunicorn.

Here is the complete docker compose file

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db: 
    container_name: my_table_postgres
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432/tcp
    volumes:
      - my_table_postgres_db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=my_table_postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=dev
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=Ieyh5&RIR48!&8fc

  redis: 
    container_name: redis
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6739:6739/tcp
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=redis-oauth-user-service
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/var/lib/redis/data/

  my_table:
    container_name: my_table
    build: .
    command: ["python", "-m", "gunicorn", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:5000", "-c", "gunicorn.conf.py", "mytable.wsgi"]
    volumes:
      - .:/api
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis

  celery:
    image: celery
    container_name: celery
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: ['python', '-m', 'celery', '-A', 'mytable' ,'worker', '-l', 'INFO']
    volumes:
      - .:/api
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.my-table.it/:/certs
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - my_table
    links:
      - redis

  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    depends_on:
      - my_table

volumes:
  my_table_postgres_db:
  redis_data:
```